# Did Nietzsche elaborate on his notion of a 'political caste to rule over Europe'

Tags: political-philosophy, nietzsche

In Aphorism 251 in *Beyond Good and Evil*, Nietzche says:

> What is serious for me ... [is] the cultivation of a new caste to rule over Europe.

And according to Nietzschean scholar Ronald Beiner, when he said 'caste' he really meant 'caste' (*Kaste*); and when he said 'rule', he really meant 'rule' (*Regierenden*); and of course when he said 'Europe', he meant Europe (N did not appear to have an authentic interest in any other worlds/cultures).

This again, according to Beiner:

> is only political innocent only on the assumption that he would never be read by people who took him at his word. We now know that assumption to be untenable.

Did Nietzsche spell out in more concrete terms how this 'caste' were to be chosen? Or did he simply assume that they would choose themselves?

Comment: what do you mean by 'Kaste' / 'caste'? i took you to mean the root "race" etc., not the meaning, 'class or order'. apologies if i'm wrong. and by 'rule' i assume you mean 'administration of law'; political not cultural etc. authority?

Comment: The idea was for "we philosophers", real aristocracy which is basic, simple, hard, ascetic, not gluttonous, etc. Instead, we got the worst out of Nietzsche, decadence.

Comment: can a nietzschean ever really argue against social and economic disenfranchisement? @Gordon

Comment: @another_name We might have more respectable leaders if they really understood Nietzsche. But what we usually get is decadence.